# How to query a React query only when the values ​of certain parameters are changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

The following is the part where I actually used React Query.

I coded as follows, and React Query keeps refetching the API.

How can I make the API call only when the parameters prodCode and pageable are changed?

```
// react-query
  const getReviewList = useQuery(
    ['getReviewList', prodCode, pageable],
    () =>
      ReviewApi.getReviewList({
        prodCode,
        pageable
      }),
    {
      enabled: !!prodCode,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        if (!_.isUndefined(data)) {
          const copiedReviewList = reviewList.slice();
          copiedReviewList.push(...data.returnData);
          // recoil state setting
          setReviewList(copiedReviewList);
        }
      },
      onError: () => {
        setReviewList([] as Array<ReviewModel>);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: why do you need to copy state from react-query to recoil? I don't see anything that would trigger an infinite fetching here ..

Answer (score 1):

React Query will not refetch. You should let React take care for that by having `propCode` and `pageable` as state variables. `onSuccess` and `onError` are meant to be used for data-related stuff, so don't update React state variables in there.

I would suggest creating a specific query class - `useReviewListFetcher`  and then use that one in your components. Somewhat like this:

```js
const useReviewListQuery = (prodCode, pageable) =>
  useQuery(
    ["getReviewList", prodCode, pageable],
    () =>
      ReviewApi.getReviewList({
        prodCode,
        pageable,
      }),
    {
      enabled: !!prodCode,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    }
  );

interface Props {
  prodCode: string;
  pageable: boolean;
}

const ReviewList = (props: Props) => {
  const reviewListQuery = useReviewListQuery(
    props.propCode,
    props.pageable
  );

  if (reviewListFetcher.data === undefined) {
    return <div>Loading.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {reviewListFetcher.data.map((listItem) => (
        <li>{listItem}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```